# What would I need to create this interactive 3d model?

Tags: 3d, webgl

I already did some preliminary research but was stumped when I found that this is another role entirely for the web. I would like to include this in a budget for an upcoming product launch so it would tremendously if I could be bestowed some details from those of you who know about webgl and its implementation.

http://assets.razerzone.com/animation/ouroboros/index.html

Comment: Could you provide more information?  I am not sure what you mean by "What do you need?"  WebGL is an implementation of OpenGL and it is not something that you will be able to pass off to a simple business or web programmer.

Comment: The product is already modeled in Solidworks which exports as .iges or .step. The plan would be to include an interactive 3d model similar to the example above on the product details page. There would only be the basic button set zoom, rotate, and reset... at least initially.

Answer (score -1):

What easiest to use is Adobe edge animation. Adobe edge makes a .obj or html code for you. So Let's say  Your Done making every animation movement what is easy. You can then export and inplent it really simple in your website.

Comment: That makes it sound a lot easier than it really is.  http://caniuse.com/webgl  WebGL is not fully supported.

Comment: That table is old as I was watching the animation on my android browser. But it really is that simple. You only need basic knowledge Of html. http://chrisgannon.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/3d-cubes-leap-motion-edge-animate-and-greensock/      hope this helps my statement

Comment: Hmmm.  Edit it so I can un-down vote it :-)  I am wondering about caniuse.  IT seems to be getting moar and moar out of date.

Comment: @KarimBouwmans how would one import the 3d object in adobe animate? Is it as straight forward as importing the model? This project would include a 3d model made in Solidworks.